# Returning Certain 'a' class Href by Date

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, beautifulsoup

I have a number of `div`tags (as shown below) that contains a `href`that I'm looking for. I can return the all of the hrefs and append them to a list but what I need to do is to just return the hrefs where the date equals the newest date in `<li class="last first date"></li>`. Any help on how I could achieve this would be great.

```
<div class="span8 story index_story genre-letter">
<a class="gtm-event" data-evt-action="/opinion/letters/article 1 on 
/opinion/letters" data-evt-category="Section element" data-evt-
label="Position 98 of 99" href="/opinion/letters/article 1">
<span class="h2">Article 1</span>
</a>
<div class="article_info">
<ul>
<li class="last first date">February 21, 2018</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You say - *return the hrefs where the date equals the newest date*. Looking at the given HTML, it's a bit hard to answer your question. Can you provide the url?

Comment: As that is a condition you'll have to do something like 
`if 'February 21, 2018' in soup.find('li').text`: do something. If no one provides a better solution I'll post a few answers.